# Use preg_match() result with (bool)?

Tags: php, boolean, preg-match

I think I will use the result of `preg_match()` with `(bool)`, but I am not really sure. I think it is not clearly that the result is not `true` or `false`.
Example 1:

```
if (((bool) preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) === true)
```

Example 2:

```
if (((bool) !preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) === true)
```

Example 3:

```
if (((bool) preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) === false)
```

Example 4:

```
if (((bool) !preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) === false)
```

An another thinking is: is the thing with result `0` or `1` safe in the future too? Do you have experience with it? What can you report?

EDIT 0: In view of `if` without comparison operators, the question is expanded. Is `0` always `false` and `1` always `true`?

Example 5:

```
if ((preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)))
```

Example 6:

```
if ((!preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)))
```

Is this correct?
`(preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches))` = `0` | `1`
`(!preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches))` = `true` | `false`
Isn't!

Comment: Why? Just use `if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) { do sth }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I just had the same thought. I have my question expand for this. Because it's not clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match()` returns 1 if the pattern matches the given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.
There are 3 possible answers. If this is reduced to a bool value (true/false), some information is lost.

```
$result = (bool) preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

`$result` is true if the pattern matches and false if not or an error occurred.

This if condition is only executed if preg_match returns 1.

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {

}
```

If not executed may be not match or an error.

A strict comparison is necessary to distinguish all 3 variants:

```
$preg_match_result = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

if($preg_match_result === 1) {
  //pattern matches

}
elseif($preg_match_result === 0) {
  //pattern not matches

}
else {
  //$preg_match_result === false   
  //an error occurred

}
```